# how to modify list items one by one as soon as each one is loaded, when number of list items is unknow

Tags: javascript, list, onload

I cannot use 'windlow.onload' or 'document.onload' also I don't know the number of list items, but I know the number is large. I want to modify list items one by one as soon as each one is loaded. I implemented the following code, but I feel like there might be a better solution. Any idea?

```
function func_loopOverList(){
  func_loopOverList.loadedCurr;//Current function call; number of loaded items
  func_loopOverList.loadedLast;//Last function call; number of loaded items

  if(document.readyState!=="complete"){
    func_loopOverList.loadedCurr=document.getElementsByTagName("li").length;
    for(var i = func_loopOverList.loadedLast; i < func_loopOverList.loadedCurr; i++){
      var element=document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i];
      //do things to element
    }
    func_loopOverList.loadedLast=func_loopOverList.loadedCurr;
    setTimeout(func_loopOverList,15);
  }else{
    console.log("Happy End");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code. Where is the ajax call that pulls the list items? Just modify the item before you add it to DOM

Comment: One issue I see with this code is that if readyState becomes complete during the 15ms of the setTimeout, any li's loaded in that time will not be processed

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified the code, change the dynamic "node list" returned by getElementsByTagName to an array - just so things don't get racey

```
function func_loopOverList() {
    function process() {
        var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

        func_loopOverList.loadedCurr = lis.length;

        [].slice.call(lis, func_loopOverList.loadedLast || 0).forEach(function(element) {
            //do things to element
        });

        func_loopOverList.loadedLast = func_loopOverList.loadedCurr;
    }
    process();
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
        setTimeout(func_loopOverList, 15);
    } else {
        process(); // one more time - this may be redundant, but it wont hurt
        console.log("Happy End");
    }
}
```

This uses array's forEach, just because, no real reason, I prefer it. You can do it with a for loop, but I just get the feeling that it's safer to work with a "copy" of the getElementsByTagName list (because it isn't a static list)